# How to authenticate with Key Vault from Azure Batch

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-batch

I've been following [this guide](https://samcogan.com/secure-credential-access-with-azure-batch-and-keyvault/) to use a certificate to authenticate with key vault from azure batch. 
Every certificate I generate causes errors on import into azure batch, some examples are listed below:

> code : InvalidPropertyValue
>   message : The value provided for one of the properties in the request body is invalid.
>   PropertyName: data
>   Reason: The specified data and the password do not match

or

> Unable to get property 'tbsCertificate' of undefined or null reference

or

> Unable to decrypt PKCS#8 ShroudedKeyBag, wrong password?

Are there any requirements for the certificate that I'm not aware of? Alternatively is it possible to assign a managed identity or service principal to my Azure Batch Pool instead, if certificates are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this article](https://blogs.endjin.com/2015/02/generating-and-using-a-certificate-to-authorise-azure-automation/) as a guide, I added the below options to the `makecert` command.

```
-a sha256 -len 2048
```

This certificate on it's own still wont work, you then need to run `pvk2pfx` with only the below options:

```
pvk2pfx -pvk batchcertificate.pvk -spc batchcertificate.cer
```

This opens the wizard, using which you then need to:

1. select "yes export the private key"
2. Tick the following options:

   - "include all certificates in the certification path if possible"
   - "Export all extended properties"
   - "Enable certificate privacy"
3. On the next page, add a password

Answer (score 0):

You can try your hand at this documentation as well: https://samcogan.com/secure-credential-access-with-azure-batch-and-keyvault/

I believe that Microsoft will publish more documentation on this specifically in the future.